# Html text box that will redirect

Tags: html

m pretty terrible at web design and i just wanted to know how to make a text box that will redirect after putting in a certain phrase and pressing enter.

Thanks for help

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
<form><input id="myInput" onblur="myFunction()" /></form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById('myInput').value == 'test') {
      window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
    }
}
</script>
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxLGgE